# How to solve recurrence relation $T(n)=T(n-1)+\lceil \log(n) \rceil$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Without the ceilings, the solution is reasonable clear (given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618778/calculating-the-recurrence-relation-tn-tn-1logn)).

Is there a way to reach a solution with the ceilings, or the difference between the two?

Comment: Are you only looking for the asymptotic (which is relatively easy) or are you looking for a closed form (which seems less likely)?

Comment: Any recurrence $T(n)=T(n-1)+f(n)$ has solution
$T(n) = T(1)+\sum_{k=2}^n f(k)$. 
In your case, $\sum_{k=2}^n f(k)$ can be estimated using $\log k\le f(k)\le \log k+1$

Comment: @Meelo I was looking for closed form.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do this solution, although you may not like it, and it might not work.
$$f(n+1)=f(n)+c \cdot \log(n)$$
We'll define c in a little bit. Also we'll start at $n=1$ and use the power and multiplication rules.
$$f(2)=\log(1^c)+\log(2^c)=c \cdot \log(1\cdot2)$$
$$f(3)=c \cdot \log(1\cdot2)+c \cdot \log(3)=c \cdot \log(1\cdot2 \cdot 3)$$
Its fairly obvious this is just a factorial...
$$f(n)=c \cdot \log(n!)$$
For generality, use the gamma function...
$$f(n)=c \cdot \log(\Gamma(n+1))$$
with $c=1$, this is a famous result in and of its self. Here's the part that might upset you. c is actually the operator for the ceiling function!
$$f(n)=ceiling(\log(\Gamma(n+1))$$

Comment: In OPs case $c$ needed to be the ceil function, but as it is not linear, your reasoning doesn't apply.

Comment: @Christoph fixed that. I guess that's true, but I really only answered because it looked like Op wasn't getting any feedback. My answer also shows the level of "creativity" that must be applied if you really want a solution.